# Express / Ajax / Axios / Trouble getting the info I need for dom manipulation

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, axios

I need to do some DOM manipulation based on some AJAX call. But I end up with the res.send on my page and I am unable to get the console.log I need to see the datas and be able to check what I need to insert in my Dom. All I see is the res.render and the JSON datas.
Even by trying to do some basic DOM creation it didnt work.

I manage to do some AJAX call already. Some Axios post, patch or delete, but I never needed to call the data when rendering the page, always through a button inside the page.

There must be something I am not understanding...

```
Router.get("/collection", async (req, res) => {
  const dbRes = await Promise.all([
    sneakerModel.find().populate("tag"),
    tagModel.find()
  ]);
  const sneakRes = dbRes[0];
  const tagRes = dbRes[1];
  res.send(tagRes);
});

// ===============================

// CLIENT SIDE => 
const allCollecRoutes = document.getElementById("allCollec");
allCollecRoutes.onclick = async () => {
  const dbRes = await axios.get("http://localhost:9876/collection");
  console.log(dbRes);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be expecting a JSON serialised response at the client but are sending a plain/text from the server i.e. `res.send(tagRes)`

Use `res.json(tagRes)` instead.

Comment: Thank you James. Actually I was trying to do a GET on a anchor tag without doing a preventlDefault so my page was reloading directly.....